# Code sections (%%) not working

Tags: matlab

I'm not new to MatLab but still I couln't find a solution and couldn't find a question about this either.

I use MatLab R2008b with windows server 2008  and sometimes when I try to divide my code in sections using `%%` it just doesn't work. The lines don't appear and I'm not able to run section (`ctrl+ enter`).

Usually a reboot or saving the file does the trick, but this time the problem is persisting.

It is worth noting that the code compiles and runs normally so that there doesn't seem to be any syntax errors or so

Any help would be appreciated ! bet it is a silly detail.

thanks !

Comment: What is your OS ? Is that the only symptom in the interface ? R2008b starts to be outdated, you may have a java incompatibility.

Comment: Cool, i didn't even know the "run section"... thanks. Concerning your problem, i am not sure, but maybe there must be a whitespace after the "%%" - at least if something else follows on that line?

Comment: Thanks guys, just found de answer. I'll update both de OS and the answer in a sec. cheers

Comment: @Thomas Sorry buddy, it's actually Ctrl +Enter not Alt for the run section !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This editor/debugger problem was actually the tip of the iceberg. The real problem was a M-Lint problem.

At the last character at the file there was a warning saying:

```
 M-lint caused your previous MATLAB session to terminate unexpectedly. Please send this message and file name 
 to MathWorks. See "About M-lint and Unexpected MATLAB Termination" in the MATLAB documentation for details.
```

So I followed the procedure found in [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95711-why-do-i-see-a-red-indication-in-the-m-lint-message-bar-in-my-matlab-file-in-matlab-7-6-r2008a-alt) in the official MathWorks forum.